# How does Daisy track the monster?

Tags: evolve

[Daisy](http://evolve.wikia.com/wiki/Daisy) is a pet that [Maggie](http://evolve.wikia.com/wiki/Maggie) gets in involve, and one of her main draws is that she's able to track the monster. However, I'm not sure exactly how she tracks the monster, which is an important detail for both hunters and monsters to know. I found [this Reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/EvolveGame/comments/2sr7ph/how_does_daisy_track_the_monster/) which states she just runs towards the newest footprint (including invisible sneaking ones) within 100m, but that's from when the game is still in beta, so I'm not sure if it's been changed.

How does Daisy's tracking work, and is there anything I can do to avoid being tracked (like running through water)?

Comment: I think it's still the same to be honest. Whenever you follow daisy there are footprints visible in front of her.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Daisy received a complete overhaul in stage 2, and the changes are listed below ([source](https://talk.turtlerockstudios.com/t/evolve-stage-2-release-notes-2-00-pc-only/87794/3)):

> Daisy AI Overhaul
>
> - Always tracks the Monster directly, choosing the quickest path to the    Monster's current location. Will no longer follow tracks.
> - Within a certain distance of the Monster, she’ll go into head-down mode and slow down to start sniffing around for the  Monster.
> - Daisy will point once she’s honed in on the location of the Monster, signalling to the Hunters that the Monster is close and able
>     to be captured inside a Dome.

Answer (score 3):

I've been the monster thousands of times and I can say out right: nothing I do as Goliath or Kraken stops Daisy from following me to one side and another. I use stealth, I run, I avoid birds, everything but she always follows me and can make a game very frustrating and out right boring.
So to be honest, I don't think Daisy has any sort of tracking skill like foot prints, smell or sound. She just follows the monster wherever it goes, which is why most players just depend on Daisy.